# Is it possible to make another way to go up a straight mining shaft in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to make another way to go up a deep mining shaft? Because after the 1.7 update water lifts will not function properly.

Comment: Ladders. It's the fastest way atm. There's a way to do it with pistons, but it has be reset every time it's used (maybe possible, but expensive).

Comment: Ladders are the fastest (and easiest) way to *build* a vertical transit system, but piston elevators are far quicker during *use*.  Teleboating (not sure if it still works) is also fairly quick and doesn't cost as much in the way of resources (mostly just wood)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Water elevators still work, but must be constructed differently.

Originally, you only needed "flowing" water to make your boat rise:

```
wSSw      Side view of elevator shaft (old-style)
wffw
wffw      S = water source block
wffw      f = flowing water
wff       w = any solid block ("wall")
wff
wffwwwww
wwww
```

However, boats no longer rise in water which is flowing straight down.  Instead, you must construct the entire shaft out of water source blocks, which takes somewhat more time:

```
wSSw      Side view of elevator shaft (new-style)
wSSw
wSSw      S = water source block
wSSw      w = any solid block ("wall")
wSSl      l = ladder or sign (to prevent spill)
wSSl
wwwwwwww
```

Here's a video of Ethos repairing his boat elevator after the change:

Comment: this will be kind of annoying if your tunnel is al the way to bedrock

Answer (score 11):

You could create a piston elevator, as seen here:

(There's a tutorial for it in the sidebar)

It's very fast and convenient, but it requires a lot of time setting up. The upside is you don't have to carry a boat with you.

Comment: ...what happens if you don't stand in the middle? Do you get crushed?

Comment: Yes, because the way it works is that when you're inside a block, it tries to push you out of it, so if you're in the middle, you get pushed back and forth all the way up. If you stand to one side, then you don't get pushed fast enough, and the gap closes leaving you stuck in a block.

Comment: Ah, hence the wave design of the pistons, I suppose. You'll get stuck for a few moments, then the piston retracts, and you drop free.